# Wordpress is messing up .. help trouble shoot

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I wrote this..

```
<?php wp_nav_menu (array ( 'conaitner_class' => 'main-nav','container' => 'nav'));?>
```

but.. WordPress displays this code as

```
class="menu-main-nav-container"
```

The class is supposed to be **.nav-conainer** but wordpress adds **"menu-main-"** infront of it

Comment: Please fix your typos!

Comment: I'm guessing `conaitner_class` is actually `container_class`. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a typo: `conaitner_class` should be `container_class`:

```
wp_nav_menu (array ( 'container_class' => 'main-nav','container' => 'nav'));
```

Also, the way you are calling this, the class will end up being `main-nav`, not `.nav-conainer`. I'm not sure where you're getting the latter.